# IntelliJ: Maven gwt:run

Tags: intellij-idea

This is my first time to try IntelliJ 12.1.4 Community Edition

I already imported my working maven project and I'm trying to run gwt:run from withing the IDE.

From the menu

`Run->Select Maven`, then input `gwt:run` to the command line. But the run button is disabled.

How do I run gwt maven from the IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

- View->Tools Window->Maven Project
- Then from the right side pane, click the Plugins item then gwt then
  gwt:run